# How to destroy token of ERC20 safety?

Tags: tokens

I have issued an ERC20 token, currently I want to destroy some of my token, how to do that? Does there have a destroy address officially, I just transfer token into it, and no one can transfer out?

Please give me advice.
Thanks a lot~~

Answer (score 2):

Your token contract only supports whatever functionality you coded into it initially. So if the contract doesn't have a *destroy* functionality you can't destroy it.

However, as the token is ERC20 compliant, even if you can't destroy the contract per se, you could just render it useless in some fashion. For example if you currently control all the tokens, you can transfer all the tokens to a void address (typically address `0x0` is used) and after that the tokens are useless and therefore the contract is useless.

If other people own tokens then you can only try to get the tokens from them and then render the contract useless. Or, depending on what functionality your contract supports, use some other means to render the contract useless.